# PHPMailer AddAttachment remote file

Tags: php, attachment, phpmailer, email-attachments

```
$remote_path = 'http://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/whatever.txt';
$mail->AddAttachment($remote_path);
```

This doesn't work because PHPMailer wants a local file, or binary data. It tried this too:

```
$data = file_get_contents($remote_path);
$mail->AddAttachment($data);
```

I don't want to download it into a local file if I don't have to. Why doesn't the `file_get_contents` version work? Is it a string and not binary data?

Edit: I get no errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should take a look at an alternative phpmailer function called AddStringAttachment:

`AddStringAttachment($string, $filename, $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/octet-stream')`

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=tutorial#3.2

Comment: and you must set: *$string = file_get_contents("mywebsite/report/…);*